# Limit of two-variable function: ${\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x(y+1)} -x -1}{\|(x,y)\|}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am stuck with this limit, which according to Wolfram Alpha does not exist.

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x(y+1)} -x -1}{\|(x,y)\|} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x(y+1)} -x -1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} \frac{e^{r\cos{\theta}(r\sin{\theta}+1)} -r\cos{\theta} -1}{r}
\end{align}
$$

From there, I thought about using the first-degree Taylor expansion in order to get rid of the exponential (which I'm not even sure I can do).

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} \frac{e^{r\cos{\theta}(r\sin{\theta}+1)} -r\cos{\theta} -1}{r} &= \lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} \frac{1+r\cos{\theta}(r\sin{\theta}+1) -r\cos{\theta} -1}{r} \\
&=\lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} \frac{1+ r^2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}+r\cos{\theta} -r\cos{\theta} -1}{r}\\
& = \lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} \frac{r^2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r} \\
&= \lim_{r \to 0\; \forall\theta} {r\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}  = 0
\end{split}
$$

This is apparently wrong, but I cannot think of any other way to solve this problem, and through this method the result is clearly 0. Since I am pretty sure using Taylor's theorem here is not allowed, how else could you go about solving the limit?

Comment: Let $f$ be $\displaystyle (x,y)\mathop{\mapsto}^{\mathbb R^2}e^{x(y+1)}$. One the one hand $f$ is differentiable (by the standard theorems). On the other hand, and by definition, it is differentiable if, and only if, $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\Bigg(\dfrac{f(x,y) - [\overbrace{f(0,0)}^{=1} + \overbrace{f_{x}(0,0)(x-0)}^{=x} + \overbrace{f_{y}(0,0)(y-0)}^{=0}]}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\Bigg)=0.$$ So if nothing better you can just go ahead and use the proof of the standard theorems.

Comment: Please clarify: are you not allowed to use Taylor’s expansion or you think that it is not applicable?

Comment: @gimusi The question is clearly stated.

Comment: @Did Let wait for an answer from the asker.

Comment: Sorry, it's that I thought it was not applicable. However, after thinking about it some more, I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @mariohm1311 well done! take a look to the solution I’ve posted, to apply Taylor correctly we need to expand to the second order for the presence of the xy term. The result doesn’t change but this is the proper way to apply Taylor’s expansion here.

Comment: @gimusi What's the rationale behind the need to expand to the n-th term for n-variables?

Comment: @mariohm1311 the exponent for $e^{x(y+1)}$ is $xy+x \to 0$ and since we have tha xy term it is not correct to expand to the first order since $xy=o(\sqrt{x^y+y^2})=o(r)$ and we need to expand to the second order. Think to $e^{x+x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Taylor’s expansion for exponential (note that we need to expand to the second order for the presence of the $xy$ term)

$$e^{x(y+1)}=1+x(y+1)+\frac{x^2(y+1)^2}2+o(r^2)=1+x+xy+\frac{x^2}2+o(r^2)$$

then

$$\frac{e^{x(y+1)} -x -1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =\frac{1+x+xy+\frac{x^2}2+o(r^2)-x -1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =\frac{xy+\frac{x^2}2+o(r^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =r\cos \theta \sin \theta +r\frac{\cos^2 \theta}2+o(r)\to 0$$

Comment: "Note that ... $\frac{ x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0$" Well, no. This ratio has no limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: @Did that’s a good and useful observation, thanks I fix